# How to control values of filters based on selections in another filter

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-filters

I have three dimension tables.In dashboard i will be having 3 slicer/filter 1-language, 2-Mat_type, 3-PO_type.

Since they are dimension tables there are no relation. But when I select a value(Chinese) in language filter, the other 2 filters should show values Chinese values.

What if I have fact tables associated with material and PO Tables.?

[image: Language table]

[image: PO Table]

[image: Material Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a true Language dimension table with three rows for your three languages. Then create relationships between it and all three of your current dimension tables (based on their Language column). That way when you select a Language (from the Language dimension), it would filter your three current dimension tables.

Here is how the relationships would look.

[image: Relationships]

And in the canvas, if you have the four slicers like this...

[image: No selection]

You can make a selection in the language slicer (note that it is coming from the separate Language dimension) and the other three slicers will get filtered. I would advocate for hiding the Language field in the other three dimensions so that they don't get used accidently.

[image: Selection]

Comment: Thanks for info, in my organization they built model the way i mentioned in the above . is there any dax query that i can use and control the filters...